# How can I get a value from realm? Java/ Android

Tags: java, realm

I get a response with retrofit. I get a acces token from `response.body()` and save it to realm. But if I'm going to use this acces token in another activity or class - how can I get the fields value?

```
@Override
public void onResponse(Call<AccessToken> call, Response<AccessToken> response) {
 int statusCode = response.code();
 if(statusCode == 200) {
 Realm.init(getApplicationContext());
 Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
 realm.beginTransaction();
 AccessToken token=realm.createObject(AccessToken.class);  
 token.setAccessToken(response.body().getAccessToken());                        
 token.setRefreshToken(response.body().getRefreshToken());
 token.setTokenType(response.body().getTokenType());
 realm.commitTransaction();
```

In another class I am trying something like this:

```
Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
RealmResults<AccessToken> results = realm.where(AccessToken.class).findAll();
AccessToken token = new AccessToken();
token.setAccessToken(result.????)
```

How can I set this value if I know only field name? I can see value in debug, but how can I get it?

Comment: `results.get(0)`?

Answer (score 0):

If you wish use only first element, I suggest call `findFirst()` method instead `findAll()`. Or if you really wish to use all of AccessToken's, you can use foreach cycle:

```
for(AccessToken aToken : realm.where(AccessToken.class).findAll())
    // call AccessToken's getters if required
```

Answer (score 0):

This tutorials shows adding removing and retriving data from realm database along with retrofit to get server response
http://blog.tamanneupane.com/simple-realm-demo-with-retrofit-and-weather-api/